# Users without enough reputation offering bounties

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

When you offer a bounty of, say, $50$ on some question to get it more focused, that many reputations get deducted from your acquired reputation. $50$ being the minimum reputation for offering bounty, how can a person offer a bounty whose reputation is less than $50$? I have seen many posts like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [privilege to set bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) is granted at 75 reputation, so it is actually impossible for a user with less than 50 reputation to set a bounty. (Note, too, that if a user once had enough reputation for a privilege but somehow loses reputation to fall below the threshold, [the privilege is revoked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67848).)

But the reputation offered in a bounty is removed from the setter's account as soon as the bounty is set, not when it is awarded; from the privilege page linked above (some emphasis added):

> **What happens when I place a bounty?**
>
> - ...
> - The reputation you're using for the bounty is **immediately and irreversibly deducted** from your reputation.

So, for example, if a user with 80 reputation sets a 50 reputation bounty on a question, those 50 reputation points are removed from their account *at that time*, and it looks as though a user with only 30 reputation has set the bounty.

Comment: If this privilege starts at $75$ then how does a person offers $50$ reputation on a bounty and yet his reputation is $1$ as here: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2V3p6.jpg).

Comment: @Reasoner: It seems you are talking about [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084587). Note that the bounty was set by the OP who has well more than 75 reputation. I believe you probably came across that question in a list sorted by activity, and that 1 rep user was the last user to be active in that question (by posting an answer).

Comment: @Reasoner I will add that even after the bounty ends, you can find out who offered the bounty from [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1084587/revisions) of the post.